# convert a string to multi dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, types

I'm having trouble converting a string to a multi-dimensional array in php. This is my string:

```
$String = a,b,c|d,e,f|g,h,y|
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
$one=explode("|",$String);
foreach ($one as $item)
{
    $one=explode(",",$one);
}
```

I'd like to create this array:

```
$array={ {a,b,c}, {d,e,f}, {g,h,y} };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with -

```
$one=explode("|",$String);
$array = array();
foreach ($one as $item){
    $array[] = explode(",",$item);
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry i don't know why it's didn't work with me in the first time 
i did it again and it's work 
maybe i made a mistake in that time 
thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
$string = 'a,b,c|d,e,f|g,h,y|';
$arr = array_map(function($iter){ return explode(',',$iter);},explode('|',$string));
```

Hope it help a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You have almost done it right, except for the cycle part. Try this

```
$result = [];
$String = 'a,b,c|d,e,f|g,h,y|';

$firstDimension = explode('|', $String); // Divide by | symbol
foreach($firstDimension as $temp) {
    // Take each result of division and explode it by , symbol and save to result
    $result[] = explode(',', $temp);
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
$String = 'a,b,c|d,e,f|g,h,y|';

$one = array_filter(explode("|", $String));

print_r($one); //Array ( [0] => a,b,c [1] => d,e,f [2] => g,h,y ) 

$result = array_map('v', $one);

function v($one) {
    return explode(',',$one);
}

print_r($result); // Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c ) [1] => Array ( [0] => d [1] => e [2] => f ) [2] => Array ( [0] => g [1] => h [2] => y ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
$String= 'a,b,c|d,e,f|g,h,y|';

$one=explode("|",$String);

print_r(array_filter($one));
```

Output will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => a,b,c
    [1] => d,e,f
    [2] => g,h,y
)
```

Comment: this one is just print array and one dim array not two also you didn't split  " , "

Comment: Please check it again please if it is producing required data.

Comment: thanks for your help but what i need is not what you wrote above you can check my question again 
the output is different